# Is there a way to get a Telerik RadEditor to not show the toolbar by default when editor.set_html(value) is called in ShowOnFocus mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, telerik, radeditor

I'm trying to simulate keypresses and clicks in jQuery, which is working to blur the toolbar in IE6 but in Firefox it seems to remain open.

Is there some way to blur the editor or some [setting](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-getting-familiar-with-client-side-api.html) that I'm missing that makes it so that it doesn't steal focus and show the toolbar by default?

**Update** it is showing up because I am calling `editor.set_html(value);` in the `OnClientLoad()` event for the editor. Is there any way to get the toolbar to hide after calling the `set_html()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling, I discovered [this post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/issue-in-set-html-and-find-of-radeditor-q2-2008.aspx):

> When the set_html() method is fired, the operation is added to the Undo list. You should use the innerHTML attribute of the editor's content area to set content in the editor

So instead of `editor.set_html(value);`, I use `editor.get_contentArea().innerHTML = value;` and now the toolbar doesn't open by default!